# MDI adding childform from different project?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I have 3 projects created by someone else.

So.. all three of them has form1.

I want to create a new window form like MDI and place them as a child.

I can't add them as the namespaces are different. Is it possible to add like this?

Coz.. the example shown is.. add new form under the current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't work.

-Make sure that the `IsMdiContainer` property of your new Form is set to true

-Add references to the other projects

-Add this code in your new windows form (the MDI parent) (assuming WindowsFormsApplication2 is the name of one of the projects):

```
//Create a new instance of the MDI child form 
WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1 childForm = new WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1(); 

//Set parent form for the child window 
childForm .MdiParent=this;

//Display the child window
childForm .Show();
```

Repeat for your other projects.

Comment: I can't call WindowsFormsApplication2 from WindowsFormsApplication1.

Comment: Why not? Did you add a reference to them in your project?

Comment: @william: Add references to the .exe files of the applications, or add the projects to your solution (if the source is available) and reference the projects.

Comment: Ok. On the Solution Explorer, There is Solution A. Under Solution A, there is project A and project B. Form1 of Project A is MDI container. I call from Form1.cs, projectB.Form1, the error states that projectB cannot b found. I m not sure wht do u mean by reference..

Comment: Ok. I get it. I have to add .exe to reference.

Comment: Rightclick projectA -> Add Reference... -> Go to the tab projects -> Select ProjectB